# How to force downgrade of iOS app without doing uninstall

Tags: ios, uninstallation, downgrade

iTunes will not sync an app with the **same or lower version**, which is (somewhat) good for users, but it is a PITA for developers. (When possible, I develop apps to be backwards/forwards/sidewards compatible so any version will work with any data.)

I am developing Enterprise applications, with different editions of the same version number.

I frequently wish to test apps with the same or lower versions without having to uninstall and then have to recreate data. I want to be able to install arbitrary versions of *.ipa files without having to uninstall the app from the device.

Is there any way to **force iTunes** to install the same or lower version *.ipa files over the app on the device?

I could use XCode, but it is not entirely convenient to check-out the previous version, build, and install, when I have the *.ipa file sitting right there.

I have looked at iPhone Configuration Utility, but it also seems to require an uninstall.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can export/import data from any version of your app out/into any other version using the organizer window in Xcode 4.2. So what I normally do is export the data from version n+1 then drag/drop the .app bundle for version n into the organizer window. Xcode will overwrite version n+1 with version N. you can then import the data from version n+1 that you exported earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about saving data. And using XCode to force a downgrade.

Comment: No problem! That little nugget of info saved my life one late night when my team and I were trying to research/fix a bad update.